# Should {bbl} be a synonym for {auxiliary-files}?

Tags: discussion

I've just encountered a question tagged with `{bbl}`. As far as I can tell this is no useful tag as most of the questions are either closed or deal with problems with bibliographical auxiliary files. So should `{bbl}` become a synonym of `{auxiliary-files}`?

Comment: don't they deal with `.bbl` files specifically? I don't see making it a synonym for auxiliary-files  would help, there isn't much in common between `.bbl` and `.aux` other than the faq about deleting them or not deleting them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought tags should be self-explanatory. Why aren't there tags for `ind`, `glo` etc. if the distinction is that important?

Comment: [tag:bbl] being about `.bbl` files seems fairly self explanatory to me. There's probably more you could say about bbl files generation via bibtex or biblatex or whatever than about .ind files , but in any case the tags get created just as people find them useful, if someone wanted to ask about `.ind` file formats, having a tag for that wouldn't be such a terrible thing. Given that the existing bbl tagged files are about bbl files I don't see what would be gained by tagging them only with a more general tag. But anyway no need to convince me either way, see what others say...

Comment: As the bbl is not only an auxiliary file but holds the complete and formatted bibliography (at least for the BibTeX system), i wouldn't treat it as an auxiliary file. This is a different case for biblatex though.

Comment: @Johannes_B So maybe it should be synonym of a bibliographic tag?